# How to populate JTable using Windowbuilder in Eclipse? (See screenshots of the GUI)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jtable

Window builder noob here, I'm trying for the first time to create a GUI for a simple program. I want to have a table on display and some slots that the user will be able to enter the data, then press a button and have them added into the table bellow. You can take a look at the GUI layout [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qlaG.jpg).

As of now I have no clear strategy of how I'm going to exactly populate the table through the slots above, if someone were to give me some guidance it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an ActionListener to your button.
2. In the ActionListener you will need to use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to update the table.